# How get sum of price by date and get null result?

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I currently have an excel file grouping articles by supplier with a price, I would like to group all the articles by date (year) by spanking the sum of the price. For now with this code I get an array like this:

```vb
Dim sql As String
Dim rs As New ADOR.Recordset
Dim arr As Variant
Const filepath As String = "C:\Users\XXXXXX\Documents\excel\XXXXXX.xlsm"
    
Dim connectionString As String
connectionString = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=""" & filepath & """;" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes"""

First_Timer = Timer()
sql = "SELECT data.[article], FORMAT (data.[date], 'yyyy'), SUM(data.[price]) FROM [data$] as data GROUP BY data.[article], FORMAT (data.[date], 'yyyy') "
    
rs.Open sql, connectionString
arr = rs.GetRows
rs.Close
```

For example with this data:

| fournisseur | article | price | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 53940 XXXXX | 1116833 | 15 | 15/10/2021 |
| 53940 XXXXX | 1116833 | 15 | 15/10/2021 |
| 53940 XXXXX | 1116833 | 15 | 15/10/2010 |
| 53940 XXXXX | 5556833 | 15 | 15/10/2019 |
| 53940 XXXXX | 5556833 | 25 | 15/10/2017 |
| 53940 XXXXX | 5556833 | 45 | 15/10/2017 |

I get this:

| arr(0,x) | arr(1,x) | arr(2,x) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1116833 | 2021 | 30 |
| 1116833 | 2010 | 15 |
| 5556833 | 2019 | 15 |
| 5556833 | 2017 | 60 |

But I would like to get:

| arr(0,x) | arr(1,x) | arr(2,x) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1116833 | 2010 | 15 |
| 1116833 | 2011 | 0 |
| 1116833 | ... | 0 |
| 1116833 | 2019 | 0 |
| 1116833 | 2021 | 30 |
| 5556833 | 2010 | 0 |
| 5556833 | ... | 0 |
| 5556833 | 2016 | 0 |
| 5556833 | 2017 | 60 |
| 5556833 | 2018 | 0 |
| 5556833 | 2019 | 15 |
| 5556833 | 2020 | 0 |
| 5556833 | 2021 | 0 |

By looking for solutions on different forums I understood that we could put IIF and a COALESCE on a SUM so that SQL returns 0 if no column with the date exists like this :

```sql
SELECT data.[article], FORMAT (data.[date], 'yyyy'), IIF(SUM(data.[price]) IS NULL,0,SUM(data.[price])) FROM [data$] as data GROUP BY data.[article], FORMAT (data.[date], 'yyyy') 

SELECT data.[article], FORMAT (data.[date], 'yyyy'), SUM(IIF(data.[price] IS NULL,0,SUM(data.[price]))) FROM [data$] as data GROUP BY data.[article], FORMAT (data.[date], 'yyyy')
```

"Arguments are of the wrong type, out of range, or in conflict with each other"

```sql
SELECT data.[article], FORMAT (data.[date], 'yyyy'), COALESCE(SUM(data.[price]),0) FROM [data$] as data GROUP BY data.[article], FORMAT (data.[date], 'yyyy')
```

"La methode 'Open' de l'objet '_Recordset' à échoué"

If anyone has a lead for me, I'm a taker

Comment: I would try something like `SUM(isnull(data.[price],0))`   not sure if i fully get what you're asking though :)

Comment: `SUM(ISNULL(data.[price],0))` give me an error : "function used with incorrect number of arguments in expression" :(

Comment: @Nathan_sav `SUM(IIF(ISNULL(price),0,price))` which looks like what you suggested to me does not work, it returns what I had previously and does not give all the dates for each article

Comment: Was that just something like this `select data.[date], SUM(ISNULL(data.[price],0)) FROM [data$] as data  group by data.[date]`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav there is still an error, I believe ISNULL is a one-argument function that returns true if arg1 is null, but even replace with `IIF (ISNULL (data. [value]), 0, data. [price])` I no longer have the articles, and if I want to do a select data.[article] I have to make a groupby data.[article] but ducou we return to the same result as before :( (except that the date formatting is no longer in year)

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_isnull.asp   Does changing `Dim rs As New ADOR.Recordset` to `Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset` help?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav no, my ISNULL always works with only one argument and I don't know why, what is the difference between these two libraries?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10916777/isnull-function-requires-two-arguments-simple-solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to a forum specializing in French VBA / Excel and it found what I was looking for, I leave you the link here : https://forum.excel-pratique.com/excel/adodb-obtenir-la-somme-des-prix-par-date-meme-quand-le-resultat-est-null-164113

in case the link dies one day or another here is the answer:

```
Sub test()
With CreateObject("Adodb.Connection")
    .Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;"""
        With .Execute("select Date2,article2,Sum(iif(price is null,0,price)) from (select  distinct Date2,article as article2 from [Feuil1$G1:G13], [Feuil1$B1:B7]) as frm Left Join (select Format([Date],'yyyy') as D,article,price from [Feuil1$A1:D7]) as frm2 on  frm2.article=frm.article2  and  frm2.d=cstr(frm.Date2) Group by Date2,article2 order by article2, Date2")
        For i = 0 To .fields.Count - 1
        Debug.Print .fields(i).Name
        Next
        MsgBox .GetString
             .Close
        End With
        .Close
    End With
        
End Sub
```

[first_columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuCnA.png)

[second_columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LCxN.png)

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2C03.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here I am again, I have not yet found the SQL formula I want but I have a good start

```
sql = "SELECT article,"

For i = 2010 To 2021
    sql = sql & " SUM(IIF(year(date) = " & i & ", price, 0))"
    If (i <> 2021) Then sql = sql & ","
Next

sql = sql & " FROM (SELECT * FROM [data$] as data) group by article"
```

[Result get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgbct.png)

It's almost what I want, I feel like I'm almost there, right now I can't get SQL to understand what I want without it crashing or giving me improbable results.